# phonebook program in c load a file in to an array of structs

Tags: c

i am having trouble with the load function it never seems to work what could i do to help debug this code;
n.b; it is required to actually load a file in to an array of structs

```
typedef struct
    {
        char FirstName[20];
        char LastName[20];
        char StreetAddress[20];
        char Email[20];
        char PhoneNumber[20];
        char DateofBirth[20];
    }phone;

void AddEntry(phone*);
void DeleteEntry(phone*);
void LoadEntry(phone*);
void SearchForNumber(phone*);
void Modify(phone*);
void SavetoFile(phone*);
void PrintDataEntry(phone*);

int counter = 0;

char FileName[256];
FILE *f;
FILE *pWrite;

int main(void)
{   int oldp=counter;
    int p=counter;
    phone*phonebook;
    phonebook = (phone*)malloc(sizeof(phone)*100);
    int iSelection = 0;
    if (phonebook ==NULL)
    {
        printf("Out of Memory. The program will now exit\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {}
        do{
                printf("%d",oldp);
            printf("\n\n\t(1)\tAdd person");
            printf("\n\t(2)\tSave added persons");
            printf("\n\t(3)\tLoad Phone book Entries");
            printf("\n\t(4)\tModify a person's data");
            printf("\n\t(5)\tSearch for Phone Number");
            printf("\n\t(6)\tDelete person");
            printf("\n\t(7)\tPrint the phone book");
            printf("\n\t(8)\tExit the phone book");
            printf("\n\nWhat would you like to do?");
            scanf("%d",&iSelection);

            switch(iSelection)
            {
                case(1):
                    {
                        AddEntry(phonebook);
                        break;
                    }
                case(2):
                    {
                        SavetoFile(phonebook);
                        break;
                    }
                case(3):
                    {
                        LoadEntry(phonebook);
                        break;
                    }
                case(4):
                    {
                        Modify(phonebook);
                        break;
                    }
                case(5):
                    {
                        SearchForNumber(phonebook);
                        break;
                    }
                case(6):
                    {
                        DeleteEntry(phonebook);
                        break;
                    }
                case(7):
                    {
                        PrintDataEntry(phonebook);
                        break;
                    }
                case(8):
                    {
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }while(iSelection <= 9);
}

void Modify(phone*phonebook)
{   int oldp=counter;
    int x = 0, i = 0;
    char searchTarget[20];
    printf("\nLast name:");
    scanf("%s",searchTarget);
    for(x=0;x<counter;x++)
    {
        if(!strcmp(searchTarget,phonebook[x].LastName))
            i = x;
    }
    if(i)
    {
        printf("\nFirst name:");
        scanf(" %[^\n]",phonebook[i].FirstName);
        printf("\nStreet Address:\n");
        scanf(" %[^\n]",phonebook[i].StreetAddress);
        printf("\nEmail:\n");
        scanf("%s",phonebook[i].Email);
        printf("\nPhone Number:\n");
        scanf("%s",phonebook[i].PhoneNumber);
    }
    else
        printf("That contact was not found, please try again.");
}

void AddEntry(phone*phonebook)
{   int oldp=counter;
    pWrite = fopen("phonebook_contacts.txt","a");
    if(pWrite == NULL)
    {
        perror("The following error occurred");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        realloc(phonebook,sizeof(phone));
        printf("\nFirst Name:\n");
        scanf(" %[^\n]",phonebook[counter].FirstName);
        printf("\nLast Name:\n");
        scanf(" %[^\n]",phonebook[counter].LastName);
        printf("\nStreet Address:\n");
        scanf(" %[^\n]",phonebook[counter].StreetAddress);
        printf("\nEmail:\n");
        scanf("%s",phonebook[counter].Email);
        printf("\nPhone Number:\n");
        scanf("%s",phonebook[counter].PhoneNumber);
        printf("\n\tPerson was successfully added to Phonebook\n");
        fprintf(pWrite,"%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n",phonebook[counter].FirstName,phonebook[counter].LastName,phonebook[counter].StreetAddress,phonebook[counter].Email,phonebook[counter].PhoneNumber);
        counter++;
        fclose(pWrite);
    }
}

void DeleteEntry(phone*phonebook)
{   int oldp=counter;
    int x = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char deleteFirstName[20];
    char deleteLastName[20];
    printf("\nFirst name:");
    scanf("%s",deleteFirstName);
    printf("\nLast name:");
    scanf("%s",deleteLastName);
    for(x=0;x<counter;x++)
    {
        if(strcmp(deleteFirstName,phonebook[x].FirstName) == 0)
        {
            if(strcmp(deleteLastName,phonebook[x].LastName) == 0)
            {
                for(i=x;i<counter-1;i++)
                {
                    strcpy(phonebook[i].FirstName,phonebook[i+1].FirstName);
                    strcpy(phonebook[i].LastName,phonebook[i+1].LastName);
                    strcpy(phonebook[i].PhoneNumber,phonebook[i+1].PhoneNumber);
                }
                printf("Record deleted from the phonebook.\n\n");
                --counter;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("That contact was not found, please try again.");
}

void LoadEntry(phone*phonebook)
{
    struct phone;
    FILE *f;
f=fopen("phonebook_contacts.txt","r");
if(f==NULL)
{
printf("\nfile opening error in listing :");

exit(1);
}
while(fread(&f,sizeof(f),1,f)==1)
{
     printf("\n\n\n YOUR RECORD IS\n\n ");
      printf("%s%s%s%s%s",phonebook[counter].FirstName,phonebook[counter].LastName,phonebook[counter].StreetAddress,phonebook[counter].Email,phonebook[counter].PhoneNumber);
     getch();
}
fclose(f);

}

void PrintDataEntry (phone*phonebook)
{   int oldp=counter;
    int x = 0;
    printf("\nPhonebook Entries:\n\n");
    f=fopen("phonebook_contacts.txt","r");
    if(f== NULL)
    {
        perror("The following error occurred:");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        for(x=0;x<counter;x++)
        {
            printf("%s%s%s%s%s",phonebook[counter].FirstName,phonebook[counter].LastName,phonebook[counter].StreetAddress,phonebook[counter].Email,phonebook[counter].PhoneNumber);

        }
    }
    fclose(f);
}

void SortByDateofBirth(phone*phonebook)
{   int oldp=counter;
    int i = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int swap;
    int TempCounter = counter;
    phone Temp;
    do{
        swap = 0;
        for(i=1;i<TempCounter;i++)
        {
            if(strcmp(phonebook[i-1].DateofBirth,phonebook[i].DateofBirth)>0)
            {
                Temp = phonebook[i];
                phonebook[i] = phonebook[i-1];
                phonebook[i-1] = Temp;
                strcpy(Temp.DateofBirth,phonebook[i].DateofBirth);
                strcpy(Temp.LastName,phonebook[i].LastName);
                strcpy(Temp.PhoneNumber,phonebook[i].PhoneNumber);
                swap = 1;
            }
        }
        TempCounter--;
    }
    while(swap);
    printf("\nYour friends in Time Order by Date of Birth:\n\n");
    for(x=0;x<counter;x++)
    {
        printf("\n(%d)\n",x+1);
        printf("Name: %s %s\n",phonebook[x].DateofBirth,phonebook[x].LastName);
        printf("Number:%s\n",phonebook[x].PhoneNumber);
    }
}

void SortByLastName (phone*phonebook)
{   int oldp=counter;
    int i = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int swap;
    int TempCounter = counter;
    phone Temp;
    do{
        swap = 0;
        for(i=1;i<TempCounter;i++)
        {
            if(strcmp(phonebook[i-1].LastName,phonebook[i].LastName)>0)
            {
                Temp = phonebook[i];
                phonebook[i] = phonebook[i-1];
                phonebook[i-1] = Temp;
                strcpy(Temp.FirstName,phonebook[i].FirstName);
                strcpy(Temp.LastName,phonebook[i].LastName);
                strcpy(Temp.PhoneNumber,phonebook[i].PhoneNumber);
                swap = 1;
            }
        }
        TempCounter--;
    }
    while(swap);
    printf("\nYour friends in Alphabetical order by First Name:\n\n ");
    for(x=0;x<counter;x++)
    {
        printf("\n(%d)\n",x+1);
        printf("Name: %s %s\n",phonebook[x].FirstName,phonebook[x].LastName);
        printf("Number:%s\n",phonebook[x].PhoneNumber);
    }
}

void SearchForNumber (phone*phonebook)
{
    int x=0,*i,j=0;
    char TempLastName[20];

    printf("\nplease type the Last name of the friend you wish to find his number.");
    printf("\n\nLast Name:");
    scanf("%s",TempLastName);
    printf("\nsearch result:\n");
    for(x=0;x<counter;x++)
    {
        if(!strcmp(TempLastName,phonebook[x].LastName))
           {
            i[j] = x;
            j++;
           }
    }
    for(j=0;j<counter;j++)
    {
            printf("%s,",phonebook[i[j]].FirstName);
            printf("%s,",phonebook[i[j]].StreetAddress);
            printf("%s,",phonebook[i[j]].Email);
            printf("%s",phonebook[i[j]].PhoneNumber);
    }
}

void SavetoFile (phone*phonebook)
{   int oldp=counter;
    fprintf(pWrite,"%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n",phonebook[counter].FirstName,phonebook[counter].LastName,phonebook[counter].StreetAddress,phonebook[counter].Email,phonebook[counter].PhoneNumber);
    oldp = counter;
}

void Quit (phone*phonebook)
{   int oldp=counter;
    fopen("phonebook_contacts.txt","r");
    if(!(oldp == counter))
        printf("The data entered isn't saved.\nAll of the changes will be discarded.");
    else
        exit(phonebook);}
```

the quit function should not include any file name nor should the print!
 I am having trouble understanding how to load a file in to an array of structs so how could this be done without leaking much memory size.

Comment: Please only ask one thing at a time. Focus on the loading problems. Describe them in more detail. Make an [mre] for that problem.

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf(" %[^\n]",phonebook[i].FirstName);`   1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  The `scanf()` family of functions returns EOF or the number of successful 'input format conversion specifiers'.  In the current statement, any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred.  2)  when using the specifier: `%[...]` and/or `%s` always use a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte.  (cont)

Comment: (cont) This also avoid any chance of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior.

Comment: regarding: `realloc(phonebook,sizeof(phone));`  This will reduce the size of the allocated memory to only the size of a single `phone` struct

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2)  regarding: `fprintf(pWrite,"%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n",phonebook[counter].FirstName,phonebook[counter].LastName,phonebook[counter].StreetAddress,phonebook[counter].Email,phonebook[counter].PhoneNumber);`  Please honor the right margin (usually at column 72 or 80)

Comment: OT: regarding: `perror("The following error occurred:");`  This would be much more informative if written as: `perror("fopen to read the phone book file failed");`

Comment: regarding: `else
    {}`  This code is a complete waste of code space.  Suggest a comment similar to: `// implied else, malloc successful`

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("\n\n\t(1)\tAdd person"); .... printf("\n\nWhat would you like to do?");`  The `printf()` function is very expensive in CPU cycles.  Suggest: `printf("\n\n\t(1)\tAdd person" ....  "\n\nWhat would you like to do?");`  with each char string on a separate line, for readability

Comment: regarding: `switch(iSelection) { ... case(8): { break; } } }while(iSelection <= 9);`  1) 9 is not a valid selection 2) the `case(8)` does not exit the 'menu --- switch' loop  2) the iSelection is an `int` so negative numbers are possible.  Suggest using `unsigned int iSelection;` and  `scanf("%u",&iSelection);`  Note the 'u' format specifier rather than the 'd' format specifier.  3) there is no need for parens around the case value

Comment: OT: regarding: `phonebook = (phone*)malloc(sizeof(phone)*100);`  in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that cast.

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("\nfile opening error in listing :");`  1) This will not be immediately displayed on the terminal since (amongst other possibilities) there is no trailing '\n' in the format string.  2) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` and when the error is from a C library function, should also output to `stderr`, the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Suggest using `perror()` as that function is made for this purpose

Comment: regarding: `printf("%s%s%s%s%s",phonebook[counter].FirstName,phonebook[counter].LastName,phonebook[counter].StreetAddress,phonebook[counter].Email,phonebook[counter].PhoneNumber);`  This will leave no spacing between the fields.  Suggest a format string of: `"%s %s %s %s %s\n"` which will space the fields and immediately output the data to the terminal

Comment: this function: `SortByDateofBirth()`  says that it will sort the phone book via date of birth, then display the resulting data in date of birth order.  However it does not do so.  Suggest searching on line for "bubble sort in c" and implementing the sort algorithm in your code

Comment: the function: `getch()` is not portable.  Suggest: `int ch;  while( (ch = getchar() ) != EOF && ch != '\n' ){;}` followed by: `getchar();`

Comment: regarding: `while(fread(&f,sizeof(f),1,f)==1)`  Besides the problems listed elsewhere, the data fields were saved with a comma and a space between each field AND the writing to the file only included the string length of each field, not the whole field,  Suggest writing the whole struct, rather than the individual fields

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note other compilers use different options to produce the same result

Comment: the posted code does not compile!. Amongst other problems, it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files.  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this line:

```
while(fread(&f,sizeof(f),1,f)==1)
```

Why do you use `f` twice? Isn't your compiler screaming at you?

`f` is a `FILE*` - it's not something that you can store data into.

Did you intend

```
while(fread(&phone,sizeof(phone),1,f)==1)
             ^^^^^        ^^^^^
```

or pephaps

```
while(fread(&phonebook[counter],sizeof(*phonebook),1,f)==1)
```

but then again you never increment `counter` ....